# Can SQL 2012 be configured to NOT require default port 1433?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to configure SQL Server 2012 to NOT require port 1433 in connection strings?

It seems that using the default instance of SQL Server 2012 requires clients to specify port 1433 in order to connect but this is causing issues when installing SharePoint.  I would like to configure SQL Server to NOT require the port.  Can this be done?

Comment: Your clients shouldn't have to specify port 1433 explicitly to connect. What exact error message do you get when clients do not specify? What protocol are you using, is SQL Browser running, is port 1434 open, is this a named instance set to run on port 1433?

Comment: see related question for the errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558952/sql-server-2012-remote-connection-setup

Answer (score 0):

Looks it is possible to configure port of SQL Server as many ways at [Microsoft's website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938/en-us).

Or directly from [SQL Server documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)

Comment: Yes i can configure the port.  The question is about NOT requiring clients to specify the port.  It seems as tho this is required on SQL 2013

Comment: All right it looks it is more about routing on your server machine. To forward automatically any request to SQL Server port.